# TikzFooter and Page Numbering

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue with Tikzfooter which I have not had before.  When I compile the tex file  the Tikzfooter (a Orange coloured node with page number does not appear on my document but no error message.  Tex files where it used to work is no longer working,  I suspect it may be when I updated.  One of the IT guys that I work with is having the same problem.

**The Script for the my working file**

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}

\input{board-formats}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tcol}{Orange!90}
\newcommand{\orr}{Orange!50!Red!90}

\newcommand{\runhead}{Document ---- 8 December 2013}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Header and footer stuff for First page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\includepdf[scale=0.95]{Cover.pdf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Contents Page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{1.75em}
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.75em}
\makeatother

 \fontsize{10}{7pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents

\newpage



\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

 \normalsize

\fancyhead[E]{\tikzheade{\thechapter}}
\fancyhead[O]{\tikzhead{\thechapter}}
\fancyfoot{\tikzfoot{\thepage\ / \pageref{LastPage}}} 

% \mainmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Agenda}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\includepdf[scale=0.8, frame, angle=0, pages=1, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{Agenda.pdf}



\end{document}
```

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:

**The script of the format file is (Board-Formats-tex **

```
\usepackage{booktabs, tikz, pgf, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem, longtable, caption, lscape}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{colortbl, hhline, comment}
 \usepackage{pifont}
% \usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}




\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10}{13pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
\newcommand{\stabsize}{\fontsize{8}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{enumi}.}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}~}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}

\newenvironment{zenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=2mm, leftmargin=*]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}



\newenvironment{zzenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=1mm]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}

\newenvironment{zzzenumerate}
{
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, itemsep=0mm]
}
{
\end{enumerate}
}


\captionsetup{margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=4pt}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% %%%%%%%%% Symbols %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% \usepackage{amsfonts}


\newenvironment{zitem}
{
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0cm]
}
{
\end{itemize}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\zrow}{\rowcolor{Orange!30}}




\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
% \thispagestyle{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter.\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-1cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol] (0,0) rectangle
          (1.1*\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,
        xshift=1cm,
        rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }


\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{cmr}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{20}{30pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
  {\thesection}{1em}{#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\fontsize{14}{16pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{\textbf{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\fontsize{12}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{b}{n}}
  {\emph{\thesubsubsection}}{1em}{\emph{#1}}


\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{15pt}{-80pt}

\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{1.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}





\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\doj}{DoJ\&CD}

\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{9mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{240mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15.5mm}
%\setlength{\headsep}{23mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10.6mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}  

\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
  \usefont{OT1}{cmss}{b}{n} {\bf #1}}



\newcommand*\tikzhead[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm,2cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.95\paperwidth,circle,
              rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=5pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large\textbf{#1}};
        \node[anchor=west, xshift=0.58cm,  rectangle,
              inner sep=3pt, rounded corners,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black} \runhead};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}


\newcommand*\tikzheade[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm,2cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.1\paperwidth,circle,
              rounded corners=15pt,inner sep=5pt,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large#1};
        \node[anchor=east, xshift=20.3cm,  rectangle,
              inner sep=3pt, rounded corners,
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black} \runhead};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*\tikzfoot[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=0cm] at (current page.south west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=\tcol, draw=\tcol, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle
          (21.6cm, 0.67cm);
        \node[xshift=10.8cm, yshift=0.3cm, 
              fill=\orr]
              {\color{black}\Large\textbf{#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\zcomment}[1] { 
\vspace{3mm}
\setlength\fboxrule{2pt}
  % \colorbox{}{
  \fcolorbox{Orange}{orange!6!white}{
    \begin{minipage}[!h]{0.95\linewidth}
      \color{black}{

        \fontsize{10}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n} #1 }
    \end{minipage}
  }
  % }
  \setlength\fboxrule{0.7pt} 
\vspace{3mm}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\lfont}{\fontsize{10}{12pt}\usefont{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}}



%%%%%% Adding in pdf pages without page break


\newcommand{\inpdf}[2]{
  \includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\chapter{#2},\thispagestyle{fancy}},
  scale=0.8, frame]{#1}

  \includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}, scale=0.85, frame]{#1}
}



%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "Board-Report-Template"
%%% End:
```